# How to use Azure Functions instead of WebJobs?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

I'm migrating to "App Service for Linux". Unfortunately, it doesn't support WebJobs. And [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/32437156--linux-to-support-webjob-feature-on-webapp-for-co) it says it won't. It suggests using *Azure Functions instead*.

I have a continuous application with no triggers. It should be always running, something like this:

```
while (true)
{
    // The logic
}
```

How should I utilize *Azure Functions* for such an application?

Comment: It is impossible to give any specific implementation details without knowing more about your application.  But if your app that is "always running" has a trigger to execute its functionality, Azure Functions can easily be set up to run that way such as on an HTTPS request, timer, etc.  Check this out for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe Azure Functions may not be the right tool for your scenario, it's best used for code that runs after some event, not for always running code.

Take a look on Hangfire, it can be executed on Linux and allows your scenario: https://www.hangfire.io/

Comment: Seems reasonable. What's the way to deploy it on azure? Deploying App Service within a web app?

Comment: yeap, it will be part of your web app or if you want, you can deploy a new one

Comment: If it's going to be continuous then I would use a container instance then just convert the webjob to a standalone app. Unless you want to use functions to somehow save cash in which case as mentioned above it will depend on what you are doing and how your webjob is triggered.